# Error coming while running android application

Tags: android, logcat

I have created an android application using eclipse but application is not running on AVD it is saying "Unfortunately  has stopped working"

Log cat message is given below -

```
07-29 04:59:50.789: W/dalvikvm(784): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidlove/com.example.androidlove.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.androidlove.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.androidlove-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.androidlove-1, /system/lib]]
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.androidlove.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.androidlove-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.androidlove-1, /system/lib]]
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
07-29 04:59:50.808: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  ... 11 more
07-29 04:59:58.399: I/Process(784): Sending signal. PID: 784 SIG: 9
```

Please help me i am tired of solving this error.....

Comment: Is you `R.java` file existing in the `gen` folder? Your `MainActivity` isn't recognized, so i guess the problem is there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186095/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse/17186174#17186174 might solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and I found the sample code was put in the "JAVA" folder instead of the "src" folder. After moving the code to src, the problem was solved.

I hope that works.

Comment: thanks it worked for me also thier is no libs folder after importing the project i also created that libs folder and add the libraries in it which were missing and now it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

add the mainActivity in menifest according your package name if package is: com.example.androidlove-1

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidlove-1.MainActivity" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: check you package name of MainActivity class and set the package name.MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare MainActivity class in the manifest.xml.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: i have added android:name but the same error persist 
  <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidlove.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>