# Android Google Drive sample code run time Exception

Tags: android

Am getting error like dis, while run the Google Drive Sample Code Help Needed??

```
07-31 00:32:10.406: E/AndroidRuntime(784): java.lang.RuntimeException:
 Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity" on path:
 DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart-1, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error coming while running android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919947/error-coming-while-running-android-application) - Search before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Please include activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity"/>
```

If it's launcher activity then use

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..I did those things.. bt again getting same error Unfortunately getting force close..

Comment: then clean your project and run again

Comment: Then look at your project settings and can you locate this class in jar or whatever you have?

Comment: Am trying Those things for a past 1hour.But not getting solution.

Comment: can you locate this class in jar or whatever you have?sry... cant get you??

Comment: What I mean is that, is this class present in you jar or in your project.